# Book on homebrew 68000 system

Tags: books

Years ago, I saw a book on how to put together a homebrew Motorola 68000 computer.  One of the specific things the book talked about was grounding DTACK*, to make a very messy asynchronous bus design into a fully-synchronous, very simple design.

Try as I might, I can't find any reference to that book.

Does anyone recognize it?

Comment: "DTACK Grounded" was the name of a hobbyist newsletter about the 68000, published in the early 1980's.

Answer (score 1):

I think tcrosley is on the right track with it being a hobbyist newsletter but the same small company that published it also sold 68000 co-processor boards using the DTACK name. There is a [site here](http://www.easy68k.com/paulrsm/dg/) that has copies of some of the newsletters and the [May 1985 edition](http://www.easy68k.com/paulrsm/dg/dg41.htm) contains the following price list:

> YE DTACK GROUNDED PRICE LIST
>
> DTACK Grande: 12.5MHz 68000:
> (for Apple II, 1 wait state)
>
> less aux. bd:  with aux. bd:
>
> 128K   $650      640K   $925
>
> 256K   $690      768K   $965
>
> 384K   $730      896K  $1005
>
> 512K   $770     1024K  $1045

Interestingly despite the name it mentions having one wait state so I'm not sure they ever achieved the DTACK grounded aim using memory technology of the day. I remember seeing their advertisements in a couple of magazines so that's probably where you recall the name from. I don't recall a design being released and the following is near the bottom of the price list:

> (Like HP, DEC and Wang we consider our CPU circuitry proprietary)

Comment: The DTACK *Grande* was a later board that implemented a single wait state to allow the use of larger amounts of more affordable DRAM (up to 2MB, iirc).  There was, in fact, an earlier DTACK *Grounded* product that used more expensive SRAM and did run with zero wait states.

Answer (score 1):

The book 'The Art of Electronics' (second editions) has a few chapters on building a 68008 based-computer; it mentions permanently grounding DTACK* on page 755.

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of the [68000 Hardware Manual](http://www.users.cloud9.net/~stark/hardw68k.htm) by Peter A. Stark, which is the successor to his *Radio-Electronics* article series about building a 68000 single-board computer that fits the PC-XT form factor?

Among other things, one of the first steps in wiring up the CPU itself is to tie DTACK* low and ground the data bus. This will treat all of the address space as `0x0000`, which corresponds to the instruction `OR.B #$0,D0`.

This causes the CPU to iterate over its entire address space as fast as it can and then wrap. The student can use a logic probe to see the address lines going high, each half as fast as the one next to it, as a cheap test that things are wired up correctly (to a basic degree).

(I've been re-reading the book, which is why I remember the details...)